# How to creating this function?

Tags: angularjs

I am very fresh when its come to angularjs .
I am currently working on a project that went cross with a angularjs library from AHN JAE-HA at http://github.com/eu81273 .This i library served me well . But i do have one problem :I am adding another value in the json formate panelsprovider list  like below

```
.add({
                id: 'test01',
                position: 'left',
                size: '1100px',
                templateUrl: 'left.html',
                controller: 'leftCtrl',
                message: '/thisDevice1')}
```

My problem was that how could i creating function that i can get the message value based on the id ,so that i could get the message by input the panel.id ?
I hope this could make sense since i am still new to angular.

Comment: It's absolutely not clear what you are asking and sorry what is the library you are using that user has a lot

Comment: Sorry. The. Library I want to use is the angular panel.    I want to modify this so that I can access each panel json property and value with matched Id